# IndexError in Python and I don't understand why

Tags: python

Python 3.7 Windows 7

I am creating a "Connect 4" program and I am having a problem with editing list values.

My code:
Don't pay attention to the doctests as I have not updated them to show changes

```
def get_piece(board, row, column):
    """Returns the piece at location (row, column) in the board.

    >>> rows, columns = 2, 2
    >>> board = create_board(rows, columns)
    >>> board = put_piece(board, rows, 0, 'X')[1] # Puts piece "X" in column 0 of board and updates board
    >>> board = put_piece(board, rows, 0, 'O')[1] # Puts piece "O" in column 0 of board and updates board
    >>> get_piece(board, 1, 0)
    'X'
    >>> get_piece(board, 1, 1)
    '-'
    """
    breakloop = False
    if row < 0:
        breakloop = True
        return breakloop
    return row, board[row][column]

def create_board(rows, columns):
    """Returns a board with the given dimensions.

    >>> create_board(3, 5)
    [['-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-']]
    """
    return [create_row(columns) for i in range(rows)]

def make_move(board, col, player):
    """Put player's piece in column COL of the board, if it is a valid move.

    """
    assert col <= len(board[1]) and not col < 0, "Move must be bewteen 0 and " + len(board[1])

    row, piece = get_piece(board, len(board[1]), col)
    while piece == "X" or piece == "Y":
        row, piece = get_piece(board, len(board[1])-1, col)
        if breakloop:
            assert "That column is full"
    return replace_elem(board, row, col, player)

def replace_elem(board, row, col, elem):
    """Create and return a new list whose elements are the same as those in
    LST except at index INDEX, which should contain element ELEM instead.

    >>> old = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    >>> new = replace_elem(old, 2, 8)
    >>> new
    [1, 2, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    >>> new is old   # check that replace_elem outputs a new list
    False
    """

    board[row][column] = elem
    return board

def create_row(size):
    """Returns a single, empty row with the given size. Each empty spot is
    represented by the string '-'.

    >>> create_row(5)
    ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
    """
    return  ['-' for i in range(size)]
```

When I use len(board[0]) or len(board[1]) it gives me back a number as expected. When I call get_board using len it gives me:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    make_move(z, 2, "X")
  File "C:\Users\comp\Documents\cs61a\Practice.py", line 54, in make_move
    row, piece = get_piece(board, len(board[1]), col)
  File "C:\Users\comp\Documents\cs61a\Practice.py", line 17, in get_piece
    return row, board[row][column]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

But when I use a number directly it works fine.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add code that creates a board and then calls the `make_move()` function so the error can be reproduced.

Comment: Can you attache code that run till the error?

Comment: you forgot the `-1` in the first call of `get_piece` in `make_move`

Comment: "*Don't pay attention to the doctests as I have not updated them to show changes*" - Then why post them at all?

Answer (score 0):

Simple speaking is like Python says, your `make_move()` function calls `get_piece()` with a value for a row or column that is out of the consented range for an index.
In particular is the seventh row of the function, where you are calling fist time `get_piece()`. You forgot a `-1` near `len(board[1])` so you'are passing 5 that's the length of your list and so when you try reading it, Python raises the error.

```
row, piece = get_piece(board, len(board[1]), col) #errata
row, piece = get_piece(board, len(board[1]) - 1, col) #correct
```